# Unable to reach a python flask-enabled web server on gce

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running a very simple http server on a VM in GCE.

The code is very simple

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json, abort

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def heartbeat():
  return 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I can reach the '/' on the server using `lynx` locally

[image]

I did not modify any firewall rules. Here is part of the rules:

[image]

Here is part of the VM information that is relevant to the networking

[image]

You can see `http` traffic is allowed.

However when I tried to connect to the server from my PC, the connection t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default python `flask` is listening to port 5000. I need a firewall rule to  allow the traffic to go through

[image]

Comment: That's correct. I ran into same problem and found the firewall in my PC is blocking 5000 outgoing - another thing that worth to check!

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a firewall rule that allows traffic to that port. In the google cloud console on your browser go to Menu -> VPC Network -> Firewall Rules. Here is a template of the rule you should create. This rule allows any traffic on any of your ports.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I deployed Flask App on GCP Virtual machine

Answer (score -1):

You can also run your app on port 80 by slightly changing your last line to:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: It's suggested that [not to use port 80 for flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086555/why-shouldnt-flask-be-deployed-with-the-built-in-server)